# Como fazer o v-money reconhecer os zeros após a virgula

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Estou usando o v-money para preços, se no banco de dados o valor não houver 0 no final como por exemplo: 10,99, ao buscar o valor e jogar no input, o valor aparece normalmente. Agora se no banco de dados o valor for 10,00, no input aparece 0,10.
A API retorna o 10,00 sem a virgula e os zeros (10), ai o v-money entende como 0,10.

OBS: Estou usando o v-money como diretiva.

Como faço para resolver esse problema?

```
<input class="form-control" id="produto-precoCusto" v-model="produto.precoCusto" v-money="money" v-model.lazy="produto.precoCusto"/>

data: function() {
return {
  money: {
    decimal: ",",
    thousands: "",
    precision: 2,
    masked: false
  },},}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer igual a isso:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      price: '123,50',
      money: {
        decimal: ',',
        thousands: ',',
        prefix: 'R$ ',
        suffix: ' #',
        precision: 2,
        masked: false /* doesn't work with directive */
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectre.css/0.2.14/spectre.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs-tips/v-money/master/dist/v-money.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="empty">
  <h1>
    Directive
  </h1>
  <input v-model="price" v-money="money" class="form-input input-lg" style="text-align: right" /> {{price}}
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

No meu caso, resolveu trocar o tipo do campo de `float` para `decimal` no banco de dados.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).